# Spanning multi-valued relationships

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, relational-database, manytomanyfield

I read the django documentation and I found something confusing!
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships.

It is stated that "*When you are filtering an object based on a ManyToManyField or a reverse ForeignKey, there are two different sorts of filter you may be interested in*"

*"To select all blogs that contain entries with both “Lennon” in the headline and that were published in 2008 (the same entry satisfying both conditions), we would write:"*

```
Blog.objects.filter(entry__headline__contains='Lennon', entry__pub_date__year=2008)
```

*"To select all blogs that contain an entry with “Lennon” in the headline as well as an entry that was published in 2008, we would write:"*

```
Blog.objects.filter(entry__headline__contains='Lennon').filter(entry__pub_date__year=2008)
```

*"Suppose there is only one blog that had both entries containing “Lennon” and entries from 2008, but that none of the entries from 2008 contained “Lennon”. The first query would not return any blogs, but the second query would return that one blog"*

So, by reading this guide, multiple questions have been created in my mind:

1- What is difference between these two types of filtering? what I know is that both of them must return blogs that contain both 'Lennon' in headline and was published in 2008. I can't find out the point.

2- The Document says this rule is just for ManyToManyField or a reverse ForeignKey. The question is, Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between these two types of filtering?

Imagine that you have a `Blog` with two (or more) entries. One of the entries has as headline some text that contains the word `'Lennon'` but is *not* written in 2008, furthermore the blog has an entry *without* the word `'Lennon'` in the headline, but written in the year 2008.

The first query with `.filter(entry__headline__contains='Lennon', entry__pub_date__year=2008)` looks for an entry that contains `'Lennon'` in the headline *and* that same entry should be written in 2008. For our sample data defined in the first paragraph, this would mean that this `Blog` is *not* selected, since the two conditions apply to the *same* entry.

If on the other hand you write this as `.filter(entry__headline__contains='Lennon').filter(entry__pub_date__year=2008)`, Django will make *two* `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s, this thus means it looks for a blog where one if the entries has a headline containing `Lennon`, and an entry (this can be a *different* or the same entry) has been written in 2008. This will thus retrieve the `Blog` defined in the first paragraph.

> The Document says this rule is just for `ManyToManyField` or a reverse `ForeignKey`. The question is, Why?

Because a reverse `ForeignKey` is a one-to-many relation, and a `ManyToManyField` spans a many-to-many relation. The `…-to-many` is important here. If that would be a `…-to-one`, it is simply impossible to make a `Blog` with two or more entries: if a `Blog` has a `ForeignKey` to an `Entry` model, then that means that the blog can only have *one* entry, not multiple ones. Since this thus limits the number of entries to one, it is impossible to have two or more entries and thus the filtering will not differentiate between the two cases.

Comment: And what would be the difference between .filter(...).filter(...) and an OR ?
Thanks

Comment: `.filter(..).filter(..)` is an AND, but not exactly as `.filter(..., ...)` since it will do independent joins.